# Make an existing Installshield 2008 package msi that runs on xp 32bits run on windows7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2008

I want to make an existing Installshield 2008 package msi that runs on xp 32bits run on windows7 64 bit??? Can anyone tell me how I can do so cause this is the first time for me to use InstallShield :(

Comment: Well, Windows 7 x64 will happily install a 32 bit msi. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with David.  Windows 7 is supposed to be smart enough to sort out 32 bit programs into the Program Files(x86) folder, and does the same "separation" in the registry.